# Pandas: reading multi-index JSON as pandas data frame

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file as follows:

```
{
    "ALPHA": [
        {
            "date": "2021-06-22",
            "constituents": {
                "BBB": 0,
                "EEE": 1,
                "BTB": 1,
                "YUY": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-09-07",
            "constituents": {
                "BBB": 0,
                "EEE": 0,
                "BTB": 0,
                "YUY": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "BETA": [
        {
            "date": "2021-06-22",
            "constituents": {
                "BBB": 1,
                "EEE": 1,
                "BTB": 1,
                "YUY": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-09-07",
            "constituents": {
                "BBB": 1,
                "EEE": 1,
                "BTB": 1,
                "YUY": 1
            }
        }
    ],

    "THETA": [
        {
            "date": "2021-06-22",
            "constituents": {
                "BBB": 0,
                "EEE": 1,
                "BTB": 1,
                "YUY": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-08-20",
            "constituents": {
                "BBB": 0,
                "EEE": 1,
                "BTB": 1,
                "YUY": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "date": "2021-09-07",
            "constituents": {
                "BBB": 0,
                "EEE": 1,
                "BTB": 1,
                "YUY": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to read the above into a pandas data frame where the first index is the date, the second index is the first keys (i.e. "ALPHA", "BETA", "THETA"), the columns are the inner keys (i.e. "BBB" ,"EEE", "BTB" ,"YUY"), and the cell values are the values of these inner keys.

How can I read that into pandas from the JSON file?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) to import the JSON to a Pandas series with `ALPHA`, `BETA` as index and elements as list.  Then expand the list of JSON to individual JSON by [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html).  Expand the inner JSON to dataframe by [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html).

Append `date` as index by [`.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True`; swap `date` from second index to first index by [`.swaplevel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html).

Finally, take the column `constituents` and further expand the inner JSON to dataframe by [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), as follows:

(assume you have already loaded the JSON file into `j`)

```
df = (pd.Series(j)
        .explode()
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .set_index('date', append=True)
        .swaplevel()['constituents']
        .apply(pd.Series)
     )
```

**Data input:**

```
j = {'ALPHA': [{'date': '2021-06-22',
   'constituents': {'BBB': 0, 'EEE': 1, 'BTB': 1, 'YUY': 1}},
  {'date': '2021-09-07',
   'constituents': {'BBB': 0, 'EEE': 0, 'BTB': 0, 'YUY': 0}}],
 'BETA': [{'date': '2021-06-22',
   'constituents': {'BBB': 1, 'EEE': 1, 'BTB': 1, 'YUY': 1}},
  {'date': '2021-09-07',
   'constituents': {'BBB': 1, 'EEE': 1, 'BTB': 1, 'YUY': 1}}],
 'THETA': [{'date': '2021-06-22',
   'constituents': {'BBB': 0, 'EEE': 1, 'BTB': 1, 'YUY': 0}},
  {'date': '2021-08-20',
   'constituents': {'BBB': 0, 'EEE': 1, 'BTB': 1, 'YUY': 0}},
  {'date': '2021-09-07',
   'constituents': {'BBB': 0, 'EEE': 1, 'BTB': 1, 'YUY': 0}}]}
```

**Output**

```
print(df)


                  BBB  EEE  BTB  YUY
date                                
2021-06-22 ALPHA    0    1    1    1
2021-09-07 ALPHA    0    0    0    0
2021-06-22 BETA     1    1    1    1
2021-09-07 BETA     1    1    1    1
2021-06-22 THETA    0    1    1    0
2021-08-20 THETA    0    1    1    0
2021-09-07 THETA    0    1    1    0
```

Comment: this is just perfect

Comment: perfect answer, very useful tips , thanks!

Comment: @Muhammadhassan  Thanks!

Comment: @AliCrash  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I feel you get better performance, and potentially easier manipulation, if you deal with python native data structures outside Pandas, before pulling the final form into Pandas:

Let's *flatten* the nested dictionary into a single dictionary, using Python's tools:

```py
container = []
for key, value in j.items(): # j is the main dictionary
    for entry in value:
        content = {'date': entry['date'], 
                   'key': key, 
                   # expand the nested constituent data
                   # this gets us a single dictionary 
                   **entry['constituents']}
        container.append(content)

print(container)
[{'date': '2021-06-22',
  'key': 'ALPHA',
  'BBB': 0,
  'EEE': 1,
  'BTB': 1,
  'YUY': 1},
 {'date': '2021-09-07',
  'key': 'ALPHA',
  'BBB': 0,
  'EEE': 0,
  'BTB': 0,
  'YUY': 0},
 {'date': '2021-06-22', 'key': 'BETA', 'BBB': 1, 'EEE': 1, 'BTB': 1, 'YUY': 1},
 {'date': '2021-09-07', 'key': 'BETA', 'BBB': 1, 'EEE': 1, 'BTB': 1, 'YUY': 1},
 {'date': '2021-06-22',
  'key': 'THETA',
  'BBB': 0,
  'EEE': 1,
  'BTB': 1,
  'YUY': 0},
 {'date': '2021-08-20',
  'key': 'THETA',
  'BBB': 0,
  'EEE': 1,
  'BTB': 1,
  'YUY': 0},
 {'date': '2021-09-07',
  'key': 'THETA',
  'BBB': 0,
  'EEE': 1,
  'BTB': 1,
  'YUY': 0}]
```

Now, build the dataframe, and set the required columns as index:

```py
pd.DataFrame(container).set_index(['date', 'key'])

                  BBB  EEE  BTB  YUY
date       key
2021-06-22 ALPHA    0    1    1    1
2021-09-07 ALPHA    0    0    0    0
2021-06-22 BETA     1    1    1    1
2021-09-07 BETA     1    1    1    1
2021-06-22 THETA    0    1    1    0
2021-08-20 THETA    0    1    1    0
2021-09-07 THETA    0    1    1    0
```

Comment: Maybe is posiibble add timings? I think this is very fast, I like this solution.

Comment: yes, it is faster; the data is a small size though, so not sure if speed tests is justified. And I don't know how to generate nested dictionaries that match the OP's form

Comment: Ya, maybe in data sample should be ouput also interesting (but necessary state is necessary also test in real for OP)